# What surface is described by $-a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = d^2$?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

I'm trying to figure out what surface is described by the equation
$$-a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = d^2$$

This kind of resembles the equation for a hyperboloid, except with a change of sign:
$$ a^2 - b^2 - c^2 = r^2 \;\;\;\; \text{(hyperboloid)}$$

I thought about some cross sections of my surface: letting $a=0$, we have a circle of radius $d$. Letting $b=0$, $c=0$, or $d=0$, we have hyperbolas.

Is there a name for this thing? A 4-dimensional hyperbola?

Also, if we write it as $a^2 + d^2 = b^2 + c^2$ this sounds like the overlap of 2 circles, does this give some interpretation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$a^2+d^2=b^2+c^2=\frac12$$
is the [Clifford torus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_torus). Furthermore, if $x=(a,b,c,d)$ satisfies $a^2+d^2=b^2+c^2$ then $rx$ does so for any $r\in\mathbb R$, so the $3$-manifold may be called a "Clifford torus cone".

Comment: Wonderful, thank you.

Comment: I have a further question if you don't mind. How would we describe the inside/outside? E.g. if $a^2+d^2 < b^2+c^2$ can we say whether we are inside or outside?