# What manifold is described by $ad=bc$?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, analytic-geometry

Consider the set in $\mathbb{R}_+^4$,
$$ S = \{ (a,b,c,d)\; | \; ad=bc,\; a,b,c,d\geq0\}.$$

What is this manifold? (I.e. does it have a name?)

For starters, I believe $S$ is smooth, connected and compact. It seems to be genus-0 since I can't think of any "holes" in the set.

Comment: Are you sure it's well-behaved at its 'edge'?

Comment: I'd say it's the set of singular $2\times2$ real matrices with positive entries.

Comment: After linear change of variables ($a = u + v$, $d = u - v$, etc.), this is your [question from yesterday](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4098155/what-surface-is-described-by-a2-b2-c2-d2), so it's a cone on part of a torus.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki By edge, do you mean when $ab=cd=0$? In my problem I'm not too concerned about that case, but it is interesting. I think that if $a \rightarrow 0$ then $b$ or $c$ needs to go to 0 at a similar rate...

Comment: @900edges The point is that if you don't have differentiability there (and in particular, if you don't have a well-defined tangent plane there), then you don't have a manifold. I haven't checked carefully myself but that is the immediate potential issue that comes to mind.